# How can i get information from Subscriber object

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Subscriber method, I am getting a Subscriber object.
But what I need is an object inside it, here is a picture - https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsP4P.jpg
So how can I get it?

**Method inside my service:**

```
getUserInfo(name: any): Observable <User> {
const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${name}`;
return this.http.get <User> (url);
}
```

**What I have inside my component:**

```
public userInfo;

this.userInfo = this.githubService.getUserInfo(this.userLogin)
  .subscribe(info => this.userInfo = info);
```

Comment: When you call your `getUserInfo` it returns a subscription and you then subscribe to it and that will give you the object you are looking for. You are assigning the subscription to your `userInfo` property and assigning it again when you subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the assignment that you are doing to your `userInfo` variable outside of the subscribe method.

```
this.githubService.getUserInfo(this.userLogin)
  .subscribe(info => this.userInfo = info);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to map your response using map function.
public userInfo;

```
this.userInfo = this.githubService.getUserInfo(this.userLogin)
  .map(response => response.json())
  .subscribe(info => this.userInfo = info);
```

or

```
this.userInfo = this.githubService.getUserInfo(this.userLogin)
  .map(response => response = response.userInfo)
  .subscribe(info => this.userInfo = info);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't assign your subscription to your `userInfo` and then re-assign it again when you subscribe.

Try:

```
public subscription;
public userInfo;

this.subscription = this.githubService.getUserInfo(this.userLogin)
                        .subscribe(info => this.userInfo = info);
```